# Javascript random generator

Tags: javascript, random

I created a random number generator in javascript whose values are in an array.
The code is that one

```js
function GetValue()
{
    var names= new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
    var random = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
}
```

```html
<p>number generator</p>  
<form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Generatore" onclick="GetValue();" class="btn btn-default" />
        <p id="message"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to give a different text in the p tag according to the number generated by the button.
Thanks very much and sorry if there is any english error

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can you provide any text example? Do you want something like this: "Text value: 123)" ?

Comment: Do you want randomly generated a string or do you want to randomly select from a list of strings?

Comment: `"give a different text in the p tag according to the number generated "` - Isn't that what the code *already does*?  In what way is this not working as expected?

Comment: yeah it works. for example i'd like to change the text in the p tag according to the number selected. for example change "number generator" into "hamburger" if it is selected the number 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the element an identifier, select it in your code and change the value according to your 'random' value:

```js
function GetValue() {
    var names = [1,2,3,4,5];
    var random = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
    var messageContainer = document.getElementById("message");
    var headline = document.getElementById("headline");
      
    if (random <= 2) {
        headline.innerHTML = 'Hamburger (' + random + ')';
    } else {
        headline.innerHTML = 'Fish (' + random + ')';
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="headline">number generator</p>  
<form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Generatore" onclick="GetValue();" class="btn btn-default"/>
        <p id="message"></p> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want, but If you want to randomly select from a string:

```
function GetValue(){
  var names= new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
  var texts = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foo2", "barbaz"];
  var random = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
  //alert(random);
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = texts[random - 1];
};
```

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x2zkph3x/

Answer (score 0):

If your question is *"How to display a randomly selected text when clicking a button"*, this is the answer:

```js
var generator = document.getElementById('generator'),
    message = document.getElementById('message'),
    strings = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

generator.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  message.textContent = strings[Math.random() * strings.length | 0];
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="generator" value="Generate">
<p id="message"></p>
```